# Setup asset pipeline for development of multisite WordPress install with multiple themes

Tags: wordpress, compression, asset-pipeline, development-environment, minify

Does anyone have a reliable local setup (on Mac) for their WordPress install using an asset pipeline? [This site](https://visible.vc/engineering/asset-pipeline-for-wordpress-theme-development/) provides an option using Gulp, but the setup is for a single theme install. I'm using 3 themes under version control. I'd like to be able to minify and compress assets on all three themes before deploying to production. Any suggested setups?

Thanks!